# Magento Collection order by filter condition

Tags: php, magento

```
$collection2 = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext_collection');
$collection2->addAttributeToSelect('sku')  
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=> 'sku','like' => $queryText.'%')))
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=> 'name','like' => '%'.$queryText.'%'),array('attribute'=> 'short_description','like' => '%'.$queryText.'%')))
        ->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addUrlRewrite();
```

I want this code should be give result order by first match `sku` with text and then additional filter of `name` and `short_description`,

Is this possible any one know ?

Comment: Are you trying to order the collection or filter it? Your question is unclear

Comment: i am trying to filter and also need to sort result by filter order it means first display records which match sku, then display name or short_description.